# Неправильное деление в php

Tags: деление, php

Есть такие выражения:

`floor (5/2)`

`floor (1.4 / 0.04)`

В первом случае выводит 2. Во втором 34. Но если посчитать на калькуляторе, то во втором примере получаем ровно 35. Без `floor` PHP считает, что 1,4/0,04 равно 34.999999403954 и поэтому округляет вниз на 34. Почему получается такое число? Типы данных float, берутся из БД.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выдержка из мануала по ПХП:

> Внимание  Точность чисел с плавающей
> точкой
>
> Числа с плавающей точкой имеют
> ограниченную точность. Хотя это
> зависит от операционной системы, в PHP
> обычно используется формат двойной
> точности IEEE 754, дающий максимальную
> относительную ошибку округления
> порядка 1.11e-16. Неэлементарные
> арифметические операции могут давать
> большие ошибки, и, разумеется,
> необходимо принимать во внимание
> распространение ошибок при совместном
> использовании нескольких операций.
>
> Кроме того, рациональные числа,
> которые могут быть точно представлены
> в виде чисел с плавающей точкой с
> основанием 10, например, 0.1 или 0.7,
> не имеют точного внутреннего
> представления в качестве чисел с
> плавающей точкой с основанием 2, вне
> зависимости от размера мантиссы.
> Поэтому они и не могут быть
> преобразованы в их внутреннюю двоичную
> форму без небольшой потери точности.
> Это может привести к неожиданным
> результатам: например,
> floor((0.1+0.7)*10) скорее всего
> вернет 7 вместо ожидаемого 8, так как
> результат внутреннего представления
> будет чем-то вроде
> 7.9999999999999991118....
>
> Так что никогда не доверяйте точности
> чисел с плавающей точкой до последней
> цифры, и не проверяйте напрямую их
> равенство. Если вам действительно
> необходима высокая точность,
> используйте математические функции
> произвольной точности и gmp-функции.